# xajax alternative?

Tags: php, ajax

I really love the simplicity of xajax calls from PHP, however xajax project seems dead by now... Is there any nice alternative or equivalent to xajax which is actively in development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in all my project, I write all javascript code using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). It's a very powerful javascript library that have complete arsenal of DOM manipulation and AJAX request code build-in it.

There are [several attempt](http://jquery.hohli.com/) to encapsulated jQuery into php, so the jQuery code can be called inside php code, and the corresponding jQuery code will be included into page output. But for myself, I prefer to write all javascript code inside the `script` tags in the `view` file (I use CodeIgniter).

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is actively developed, and the latest version (1.4) is just launched a few days ago.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was also thinking about using jQuery, do you have any more examples for encapsulating jQuery into PHP?

Comment: Just click my link above: http://jquery.hohli.com/ 
I don't know much about it, since like I write in my answers, I prever write javascript in the page, not in PHP code, because that's what work for me all this time. Since I also use CodeIgniter, I can keep the controller code at minimal with this way.

Comment: By writing the javascript code in html output file part, I can test the code in the static html, before put it in actual PHP code. The template is usually provided by other colleague or my client, so I just concentrate on js code and PHP in back end. I make it work without js first, then do progressive enhancement with js code. That's another reason why I put js code in html, not in PHP backend, since it's just to enhance, not the main feature. Without it, my application still can work.

Comment: I have a project where it has been relying heavily on xajax since the beginning. It will be very difficult to switch into just using jquery since there will be a lot of additional javascripts needed in pages. Just to make our work lighter, I need to find an alternative to it.

Comment: My suggest is that you do progressive update, rather than replace all of it. For now, leave the already worked page, and use jQuery for new page, so you can learn while use it. It will help you understanding the jQuery more better. After you successfully create new page, then start to convert existing pages, one at a time from xajax to jQuery. After this go smooth, in your next project, you can safely start using jQuery since beginning. Just a suggestion, since this is what I do the first time I learn jQuery a few years ago.

Answer (score 3):

A new alternative to Xajax is sijax.
While official support is listed under the python module, there is a github hosted project of sijax.  It is a PHP library that integrates JQuery and xajax object mentality to allow for a quick and simple usecase but a powerful backend.

https://github.com/spantaleev/sijax

Comment: Sijax seems pretty great. Documentation is a bit lacking for PHP integration, but it's clearly an excellent tool. I'm a heavy XAJAX user, and am considering replacing XAJAX with Sijax entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, please have a look at [PHPLiveX](http://www.phplivex.com/). It is light-weight, and there with the continued development. Thanks

**Example Code:**

```
 function generateRandomCode($length){  
   $chars = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","a","b","c","d","e","f");  
   $code = array_rand(array_flip($chars), $length);  
   return implode($code);  
 }  

 // Necessary PHPLiveX Codes   
 include("PHPLiveX.php");  
 $ajax = new PHPLiveX(array("generateRandomCode"));  
 $ajax->Run(); // Must be called inside the 'html' tags.  

<input onclick="generateRandomCode(10, {'target':'rcode','preloader':'pr'});"   
type="button" value="Generate Random Code" >  
<img id="pr" src="design/Progressbar2.gif" style="visibility:hidden;">  
<span id="rcode"></span>
```

Comment: I can see the last release date older than xajax o.O The forum is also cold... Is it really still actively in development?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a more advanced PHP / jQuery / AJAX library than my library Phery ( http://phery-php-ajax.net/ ), been using it and coding it for over 2 years now. The tight coupling with everything jQuery has to offer is esplendid, and supports past, present and future versions of jQuery automatically

You may even access the original calling element using `PheryResponse::factory()->this()`, you can manipulate any DOM on the page directly from inside PHP, and even pass raw javascript callbacks to jQuery from PHP, using `PheryFunction` class

Example code:

```php
Phery::instance()
->set(array(
// You don't need to use lambda functions, but it's the power of PHP 5.3 ;)
'alias-for-function' => function($ajax_data){
  ob_start();
  var_dump($ajax_data);
  $data = ob_get_clean();

  return
    PheryResponse::factory('#result')
      ->html($data)
      ->jquery('body')
      ->css(array('backgroundColor' => 'red'))
      ->alert('This is an alert')
      ->script('window.setTimeout(function(){ $.callRemote("alias-for-function", {"new":"data","on":["the","block"]]}); }, 1500);')
      ->call('javascript_function', 'arg1', 'arg2', 3, array(1,2,3))
      ->this()
      ->height(100)
      ->width(100)
      ->getJSON('http://jsonurl', PheryFunction::factory(array(
        'function(data){',
          'console.log(data);',
        '}'
      )));
  }
 ))
 ->process();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of [KSS-RPC](http://www.joonis.de/kss), a complete rewrite of the aged [KSS project](http://kssproject.org/).

**Summary:**

> KSS (Kinetic Style Sheets) is a framework that allows Ajax development without writing more JavaScript. It uses stylesheets with CSS-compliant syntax to declare behaviours in the client and a set of well-defined DOM-like commands that are sent back from the server to manipulate the HTML page.

**Features:**

- Supported protocols: JSON-RPC, XML-RPC and URL-encoded requests
- Supports all modern browsers inclusive IE9+ (IE8 with polyfills)
- Independent from any third-party JavaScript library
- Optional supported selector engines: Sizzle (jQuery) and Slick (MooTools)
- Supported animation libraries: Velocity, GreenSock, jQuery and MooTools

Answer (score 0):

The Xajax library has been forked. The [Jaxon library](http://www.jaxon-php.org) provides the same features as Xajax, and many more like directory export, namespace support and autoloading.