# CakePHP: Component class XAjaxComponent could not be found

Tags: php, cakephp, xajax

Sorry for the lengthy post. I try to be as specific as I can with my question. I have been having problems migrating a cakephp1.2 site to cakephp2.x. I am new to cakephp and have read and follow the migration manual and docs at [Cakephp website](http://cakephp.org).

So far so good but I can only view logo, and background of the site but no content was loaded. And I also receive an error :

An Internal error has occurred. 
**Component class XAjaxComponent could not be found**

In the stack trace:

"CORE/Cake/Controller/ComponentCollection.php line 53 → ComponentCollection->load(string, array)
'XAjax'
array()"

I didn't see and find any XAjax information in the manual and the website. The previous developer have included XAjax as a component array in the AppController.

```
public $components = array( 0 => 'RequestHandler', 1 => 'Security', 2 => 'Auth',  3 => 'XAjax', 4=> 'DebugKit.Toolbar', 5 => 'Cookie', 6 => 'Session' );
```

In a [thread somewhere here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126410/xajax-alternative) I read that [XAjax](http://www.xajax-project.org/) is no longer actively maintained (last updated was in 2012 and is still in beta)? And suggest using alternatives like jQuery?

As i browse the app files I found out XAjax is used to call the following functions(listed below in no particular order):

```
$this->XAjax->autocomplete( $param_encode, $param_hash, $conditions );
$this->XAjax->flashuploadset($this->request->data);
$this->XAjax->normalupload($this->request->data, false);
$this->XAjax->flashuploadset($this->request->data);
```

These have something to do with forms. I couldn't find any XAjax function anywhere or any XAjax plugin or component for that matter for the class to be called. I am not very familiar with XAjax actually.

My question is if I were to still want to implement XAjax in my cakephp site, then how best should I do it?

Any form of help or suggestions will be very much appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: The component you are refering to isn't part of CakePHP - so it's absolutely no surprise there are no references to it I  Cake's documentation.  Folder names became Cased in 2.0 - most likely yoy app/plugin still needs migration-steps applied to it.

Comment: @AD7six - Yes it's not part of cakephp that I'm aware of, so I assume the previous developer must have integrated it and packaged it in  vendors (since its initially a cake 1.2)..probably. But I have trouble locating any files of it in plugins or vendors folders. So i'm pretty much stuck as it is.. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(CakePHP 3.0) If you're using a custom component (or writing your own like I am) you need to specify your namespace at the top of your controller, and tell your component where it can find the Component class. I received a similar error in my application:

> Missing Component
>   Error: SuperComponent could not be found.
>
> Error: Create the class SuperComponent below in file: src/Controller/Component/SuperComponent.php

```
<?php
class SuperComponent extends Component {

}
```

The file src/Controller/Component/SuperComponent.php already existed, but I needed to add these lines at the top (under

```
namespace App\Controller\Component;
use Cake\Controller\Component;
```

Comment: `I have been having problems migrating a cakephp1.2 site to cakephp2.x` => Why do you think he needs to use 3.0 now?

Comment: I'm not suggesting a migration to 3.0--just providing a solution for those out there who are on 3.0 who are running into the same issue.